# How to get element from another element selenium using WebDriverWait?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Please see this:

```
IWebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait WebDriverWait;

public IWebElement Button
{
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("bla bla")));
}
```

Now in case I want to search some `IWebElement` but instead of `driver.FindElement` I want to use another `IWebElement` I can do the following:

```
IWebElement webElement..
IWebElement webElement e = webElement.FindElement(By.XPath("my selector"));
```

So in this case I want to use `WebDriverWait` to instead of just `webElement.FindElement`.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebDriverWait.Until()` returns `IWebElement`, you can assign the returned value to a variable or just concat another method

```
IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("bla bla")));
element.FindElement((By.XPath("my selector"));
```

Is the same as

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("bla bla"))).FindElement(By.XPath("my selector"));
```